# how can i use surf feature in hierarchical clustering

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, sift

First,Is it true to extract surf feature and use them in clustering? I want to cluster similar objects in images ?(each image contain one object)

If yes,how is it possible.
I extract features like this:

```
I = imread('cameraman.tif');
points = detectSURFFeatures(I);
[features, valid_points] = extractFeatures(I, points);
```

features is not a vector and is a matrix.Also number of points extracted by 'detectSURFFeatures' differ in different images.
   how should features use?

Answer (score 1):

First, you are detecting SURF features, not SIFT features (although they serve the same basic purpose). The reason you get multiple SURF features is that SURF is a local image feature, i.e. it describes only a small portion of the image. In general, multiple features will be detected in a single image. You probably want to find a way to combine these features into a single image descriptor before clustering.

A common method for combining these features is [Bag-of-words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bag-of-words_model_in_computer_vision).

Since it seems you are doing unsupervised learning, you will first need to learn a codebook. A popular method is to use [k-means clustering](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html) on all the SURF features you extracted in all of your images.

Use these clusters to generate a k-dimensional image descriptor by creating a histogram of "codeword appearances" for each image. In this case there is one "codeword" per cluster. A codeword is said to "appear" each time a SURF feature belongs to its associated cluster.

The histogram of codewords will act as an image descriptor for each image. You can then apply clustering on the image descriptors to find similar images, I recommend either normalizing the image descriptors to have constant norm or using the cosine similarity metric (`kmeans(X,k,'Distance','cosine')` in MATLAB if you use k-means clustering).

---

That said, a solution which is likely to work better is to extract a deep feature using a convolutional neural network that was trained on a very large, diverse dataset (like ImageNet) then use those as image descriptors.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I use [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44914225/clustering-surf-features-of-an-image-dataset-using-k-means-algorithm?rq=1) first, but  i don't understand how should i create histogram of codeword and then how to use it?

Comment: For each image run the `histogram` function on the subset of values in `assignments` corresponding to the features of that image. Make sure to always define the histogram bin edges as `0.5:(k+1)`.